# Validating null query in if clause

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple Linq query And a `if...else` conditional like :

```
var incidenciaPronosticada = _c.IncidenciaPronosticadas
    .Where( x => x.IdIncidenciaPronosticada == item.IdIncidenciaPronosticada )
    .FirstOrDefault();

if( incidenciaPronosticada.IdIncidenciaPronosticada != 0 || incidenciaPronosticada.IdIncidenciaPronosticada != null )
{
    //code there
}
else {
    //code there
}
```

problem is when `incidenciaPronosticada` comes null it don't execute `else` clause, it just stop

> incidenciaPronosticada.IdIncidenciaPronosticada =
>   'incidenciaPronosticada.IdIncidenciaPronosticada' threw an exception
>   of type 'System.NullReferenceException'

Why it don't read `incidenciaPronosticada.IdIncidenciaPronosticada != null`? It's supossed if debugger read it it should pass to else clause no? Or what am I doing wrong? Regards

Comment: Because you cant do a !=0  and != null on same check, it is trying to compare 0 to null if your objec tis null.  You can do a nested if, check if null first, then if !=0

Comment: First you need to check if `incidenciaPronosticada` is null or not. And then check `if(incidenciaPronosticada.IdIncidenciaPronosticada.HasValue && incidenciaPronosticada.IdIncidenciaPronosticada.Value !=0)`

Comment: probably you want to do the check the other way, `if ( incidenciaPronosticada!= null && incidenciaPronosticada.IdIncidenciaPronosticada.HasValue && incidenciaPronosticada.IdIncidenciaPronosticada.Value != 0)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`incidenciaPronosticada` itself can be null, which means `incidenciaPronosticada.IdIncidenciaPronosticada != 0` will cause a `NullReferenceExecption` because `IdIncidenciaPronosticada` cannot be accessed.

Either perform an explicit null check or use the null-safe navigation operator `?.`:

```
if( incidenciaPronosticada != null && incidenciaPronosticada.IdIncidenciaPronosticada != 0 ) {
```

or:

```
if( incidenciaPronosticada?.IdIncidenciaPronosticada > 0 ) {
```

(Note I used `> 0` instead of `!= 0` because `> 0` will be `true` if `incidenciaPronosticada` is null (because `(Int32?)null != (Int32?)0`):

Also note the type of the `incidenciaPronosticada?.IdIncidenciaPronosticada` expression is `Nullable<Int32>` (aka `Int32?`) and not `Int32`.

Here's a table of outcomes for `if( incidenciaPronosticada.IdIncidenciaPronosticada ... )`

```
incidenciaPronosticada      IdIncidenciaPronosticada    . != 0    . > 0
null                        null                        throws    throws
(object)                    null                        true      false
(object)                    0                           false     false
(object)                    1                           true      true
```

Here's a table of outcomes for `if( incidenciaPronosticada?.IdIncidenciaPronosticada ... )`

```
incidenciaPronosticada      IdIncidenciaPronosticada    ?. != 0   ?. > 0
null                        null                        true      false
(object)                    null                        true      false
(object)                    0                           false     false
(object)                    1                           true      true
```

Comment: Pay attention: if `incidenciaPronosticada` is null, then `incidenciaPronosticada?.IdIncidenciaPronosticada != 0` will evaluate to true

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access a member inside incidenciaPronosticada. Your null check should look like

```
if(incidenciaPronosticada != null)
{
//code there
}
else {
//code there
}
```